# react child calling parent function is slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried to keep this as brief as possible, but with enough detail.

I have a yearly calendar which I need to be interactive so that when you click on a date and drag the mouse across to another date, all dates within the current dragged range have their class changed dynamically in a temporary state. An `onMouseUp` event would then make the temp changes permanent.

The calendar is broken down in to class objects so that:

```
<Year>
    <Month>
        <Day>
            <Shift {some state values from Year need to be passed here}/>
        </Day>
    </Month>
</Year>
```

`<Year>` contains some functions that changes some states in the constructor for `<Year>` - namely a start and end date. This function is passed all the way to `<Shift>` so that when there's an `onMouseDown` event a the `<Shift>` level it calls the function in `<Year>` that sets the start date.

Additionally hovering sets an end date using the same process, so clicking one then dragging across many `<Shift />` components will set a start and end date at the `<Year>` level. When the user is happy with their selection, an `onMouseUp` event would commit these changes to a permanent display.
This start and end date was intended to be used in each `<Shift />` component to determine the CSS class used for rendering for that `<Shift>`.

Turns out that simply calling the date setting functions slows the whole thing down dramatically and there's massive lag in the drag event, even when I modify the code so that the start and end dates literally do nothing except be stored in `<Year>`.

It's like I'm re-rendering the whole `<Year>` component unnecessarily, meaning all others get re-rendered too, but since the start and end dates aren't even being passed anywhere, I don't see how?

Any help on restructuring the work flow would be appreciated.

Comment: try adding `shouldComponentUpdate() { return false; }` to your `Year` component to verify that the re-render is the problem

Comment: Thanks. Yep, can confirm that it's the re-render that's the problem as a simple console log prints as fast as i can move the mouse, where as without your addition there's ~0.5s or more delay. Do I need to use Redux here to control the states before re-rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `PureComopnent`s instead of `Component`s (or alternatively make use of `componentShouldUpdate()` with clearly defined logic) and use immuatableJS to ensure I used proper immutable objects... which I clearly had not (shame on me!)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're constantly updating the state as you're hovering. To avoid that use a debouncer so you only update the state at the end of the hover:

```
// Shift component

debounceSetEnd(date) {
   clearTimeout(this.timer);
   this.timer = setTimeout(() => this.props.setEnd(date), 1000);
}

onMouseEnter={() => this.debounceSetEnd(this.props.date)}
```

Comment: Not quite. The state is updating only as I move the mouse from shift to shift, but not while hovering still. I'm using the `onMouseEnter` to set the end date while hovering. I think I'm correct... right? Not continually updating unless the mouse hovers over a new shift?

Comment: what are you console.logging that's printing fast? debounce that

Comment: the console.log is the date prop of the shift that's being hovered over. `onMouseEnter={()=>this.props.setEnd(this.props.date)}` where setEnd is from `<Year>`

Comment: I've created a `mouseEnterDetected()` method inside `<Shift>` so `onMouseEnter` calls `mouseEnterDetected` which calls `setEnd()`. But I'm not sure I understand how to apply the debounce to that method?